# video stop after few seconds while playing video from URL using MPMoviePlayerController with error in the console

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

im using MPMoviePlayerController to play video for givin URL , some times after few seconds of playing the video stop and prit this message to the console

**Took background task assertion (6) for playback stall.**

what could be the error

Thanks

Comment: Show your code how you play video?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no error actually media player is downloading your video after completing the download it will show this message

**Ending background task assertion (6) for playback stall**

and then video will be played automatically

Comment: But the problem is that it stops the video

Comment: is there any notification or delegate to catch the event